# jQuery radio button change function not being triggered when it should

Tags: radio-button, jquery, eventtrigger

I have a problem with this jQuery Change function:

```
<input type="radio" name="words" value="8" checked><span class="word">word1</span>
<input type="radio" name="words" value="6"><span class="word">word2</span>

$("input[@name='words']:checked").change(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

The problem is that the event gets only triggered when I click the first option (value=8) which is checked by default.

How Can I trigger the event when clicking any other option?

Please note: I have tried the above function on both Chrome and Firefox and I have the same problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be `$("input[name='words']").change(function(){`

Answer (score 1):

You are only binding the event handler to `:checked` elements. So as the first `input` has the `checked` property set, that's the only one that receives the event handler. Remove `:checked` and it should work fine:

```
$("input[name='words']").change(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/13/). Note that I've also removed the `@` character from your selector. You haven't needed it since like jQuery 1.2 or something like that.

Comment: you example works but the `@name` is wrong in you code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[@name='words']:checked").change(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

You've subscribed change function only to the radiobuttons whitch is checked (`:checked`). Remove it from selector.

```
$("input[name='words']").change(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/DRasw/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[@name='words']:checked").change(function(){
```

That finds all the `input` elements with the name `words` (actually, it won't work: the XPath-style `@` attribute selector has been removed since jQuery 1.3) that are checked and binds an event handler to them. If the elements are not checked when the selection is made, no event handlers will be bound to them.

The easiest solution is to bind to *all* relevant elements, and only fire code if they have been unchecked:

```
$('input[name="words"]').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) { // checkbox was checked, now is not
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Give id property of Radio buttons
2. Add property of OnClick="CheckClick()" on second redio button.
3. In jquery CheckClick()  function

   if ($('#rb2').attr('checked')) {
       alert('rb2 test');
   }

Answer (score 1):

[working link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4vb/5/)

```
  $("input[name='words']").change(function(){
alert("test");
 });
```